# How to add border to the arrow of the Popover?

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I've created a view of a popover something like this (Mind the color). Is there any way I can add the border to the Popover?

I've tried using the UIBezierPath to carve out the pattern but it wasn't working. Is there something else I could do?

```
  class IncutoNotifTableArrow: UIView {

func bezierPathArrowCut() -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 10.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width) * 0.24 - 20.0), y: 10.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width) * 0.24 - 40.0), y: 0.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width) * 0.24 - 60.0), y: 10.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 10.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.height))
    print(path.cgPath)

    path.close()
    return path
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let path = bezierPathArrowCut()
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    path.fill()
}



}
```

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE3uk.png)

[This is the Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3tWh.png)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a subclass of `UIPopoverBackgroundView` that does your custom drawing. Then set the `popoverBackgroundViewClass` on the `UIPopoverPresentationController` to be your subclass.

Comment: can you please provide an example. I tried a few ways but couldn't customize the border.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ElegantPopover](https://github.com/prasad1120/ElegantPopover) library to get it done. The library would do the manual drawing part of the border. You need to pass arguments for border color and width and arrow metrics.